# how to pass props to Nav.Link of react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap, react-props

I am using the following Navbar. I would like to pass some props to Nav.Link. I don't know how to pass the property to Nav.Link. Or is it just like HTML href="a.html?param=test"?

```
    const Navigation = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Dating Service</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/CreateProfile">Create Profile</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="/ViewProfile">View Profile</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing props to your `Navigation` component, which is alright; you can use the props in `Nav.Link` like:

```
<Nav.Link href={links[0].url}>{links[0].label}</Nav.Link>
```

sample **js**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";

const Navigation = ({ name, links }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">Dating Service</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              {links.map((val, indx) => {
                return (
                  <Nav.Link key={indx} href={val.url}>
                    {val.label}
                  </Nav.Link>
                );
              })}
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
      <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
    </>
  );
};
export default Navigation;
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ftryop)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can see u are making Navbar from the state which is a JSON type. And generating the Navbar by looping the JSON data. But I don't see any parameter is passed. I have to pass the parameter. Something like my href=/apaht/aparameter. Later I have to get the parameter on the landing url.

Comment: Open the stackblitz link... the 2 props (name and link) are being passed as props to this component - hope it helps

Comment: I see and it will solve my problem with few changes. Thx

Answer (score 1):

In Reactjs 18.6 You can pass props as link and then can have access in your destination page by useLocation(). The sample below shows you how to pass props

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ContactItem = ({ item }) => {
return (
<Nav>
   <Nav.Item>
      <Nav.Link as={Link}
      to={{
        pathname: '/َcontactform',
        state: { currentContact: item},
      }}
     >
     <i className="far fa-edit"></i>
     </Nav.Link>
   </Nav.Item>
</Nav>

)}
    
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const ContactForm = () => {
  let location = useLocation();
  const { currentContact} = location.state;

  console.log(currentContact)
  return (  ... Components ...  )

}
```

Comment: You meant 16.8 !!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here in 2024.

```
<Nav.Link 
  as={Link} 
  to="/account-type" 
  state={{ stateLink: "myState" }}
  className="ps-0 py-2"
 >
   Home
</Nav.Link>
```

And then in the page you navigated to. You can access by:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
let location = useLocation();
const { stateLink } = location?.state;

console.log(stateLink) //myState
```